# Can a company have several "labels" in App Store?

Tags: app-store

(Not sure if this is completely on topic for stackoverflow - if not, let me know!)

We're considering setting up a "label"/sub-brand for our company on app store. Has anyone else tried this? Do you need to set up a separate bank account etc to do so?

(I've googled, and tried mailing Apple, but no luck).

Comment: Not holding your breath for a personal reply from Steve Jobs?

Comment: I've tried holding my breath, too, but it didn't help. (Well, really, I mailed their support).